# Fiscal year and fiscal quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, fiscal

I have a table where I store order dates YYYY-MM_DD.

How do I create fiscal year and fiscal quarter with the following requirements:
Fiscal years:

1. start date for Fiscal_Year_2000 is 1999-07-01 and ends on 2000-06-31
2. start date for Fiscal_year_2001 is 2000-07-01 and end on 2001-06-31

Fiscal Quarters:

1. Fiscal_Quarter_1 for example FY2000 starts 1999-07-01 and ends 1999-09-31
2. FQ2, FQ3, FQ4 for FY 2000
3. FQ1/2/3/4 for FY2001

I tried

```
WHERE  OrderDate BETWEEN '1999-07-01' and '2001-06-31'
DATEADD (month,7,OrderDate) AS [OrderDateNew],
DATEPART(Year, [OrderDateNew]) as [FY], 
DATEPART(QUARTER, dateadd(month,3,[OrderDateNew])) as [FQ]
```

I am getting some very odd results. Any help is highly appreciated.

Output should be something like:

```
FY     FQ   Some other data columns of products, sales etc
2000   1
2000   2
2000   3
2000   4
2001   1
2001   2
2001   3
2001   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add six months and use the year.  For instance, if you want FY 2000:

```
where year(dateadd(month, 6, orderdate)) = 2000
```

If you want the FY year and quarter, use the same idea:

```
select year(dateadd(month, 6, orderdate)) as fyear,
       datepart(quarter, dateadd(month, 6, orderdate)) as fquarter
```

Comment: why do we add "6" and not "7" above?

Comment: 1999-07-01 + 6 months = 2000-01-01 which would start your FY2000